# How can I route SMSes using Twilio, based on a schedule?

Tags: sms, twilio

I send SMS alerts to my mobile phone using Twilio; I would like to route this to a different number based on a schedule / rota?  ie I am in the US, so during my day I would like to get alerts, and then during the UK's day I would like someone else?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just configure the sending address based on the current date and time. In Python this would look something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

curr_time = datetime.utcnow()

# roughly, London working hours
if 8 < curr_time.hour <= 17:
     recipient = "+44XXXXXXXXXXX"
else:
     recipient = "+1XXXXXXXXXXXX"

send_sms_message(from=twilio_number, to=recipient, body=body)
```

Without knowing more about how you are sending the messages, or how you are generating alerts, it's difficult to provide a more nuanced answer.

Comment: Hi kevin, thanks for your answer.  I am sending the alerts from Zendesk, and as such I don't have control over the code sending it; I was hoping Zendesk could send to one number, then I could forward on from that number based on some rules.  Twilio doesn't seem to do this; I was wondering if a 3rd part did?  I could do it myself but I don't want to host a service just for this.

Comment: (Twilio employee here) I think you can definitely do this with Twilio. Basically, you need a proxy. You would have Zendesk send the message to a Twilio number. Then that number collects the message, figures out the number to forward to, and then sends it. The code behind it should be relatively simple.